# How can I Automate file to directory transfers in debian/ubuntu?

Tags: linux, bash, cron

so I'm currently in the middle of attempting to automate file transfers. I've tried cron and rsync but keep throwing error, which I can update here if need be. The point, if this helps, is to automatically transfer files from one directory to multiple directories. File1 exists in Dir1 and I need to to mv File1 to Dir2, Dir3, Dir4, Dir5 and so on. File1 is THE only file that needs to be relocated, however, I need this file to randomly "hop" from 1-10 directories thorughtout the day. I am running cloud instance so the machine will be up and running through the day and night.

What I've tried so far:

```
0 0 1  * * cp -fr /path/to/file /path/to/destination/A
0 0 8  * * cp -fr /path/to/file /path/to/destination/B
0 0 15 * * cp -fr /path/to/file /path/to/destination/C
0 0 22 * * cp -fr /path/to/file /path/to/destination/D
```

Error: 0: not a command

and

```
0 1 1 * * rsync -avz  /path/to/directory /path/to/destination/A
0 1 8 * * rsync -avz  /path/to/directory /path/to/destination/B
0 1 15 * * rsync -avz  /path/to/directory /path/to/destination/C
0 1 22 * * rsync -avz  /path/to/directory /path/to/destination/D
```

Same Error

and

```
cd () { builtin cd "$@" && chpwd; }
pushd () { builtin pushd "$@" && chpwd; }
popd () { builtin popd "$@" && chpwd; }
unset_all_project_settings () {
  # do whatever it takes to undo the effect of projectSettings.bash,
  # e.g. unset variables, remove PATH elements, etc.
}
chpwd () {
  case $PWD in
    /some/directory|/some/other/directory) . ./projectSettings.bash;;
    *) unset_all_project_settings;;
  esac
}
```

Issue here is that I'm unsure how to proceed with the where and how to get this function up and running.

Comment: "Error: 0: not a command" -- when do you get this message? It looks like you are trying to run the `crontab` file by itself...

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. So, after running: 0 0 1  * * cp -fr /path/to/file /path/to/destination/A, is when i reciueve the error. Am i missing a prefix?

Comment: I think, you missed documentation reading. The lines you mentioned should be placed into the `crontab` file which directs the `cron` which tasks should be run and when. Run the `man 5 crontab` command and you'll get to know something interesting.

Comment: Is it that obvious? Im a cron NOOb haha. Listen, I'm really just testing thing out right now. Any suggestion on how you would go about this?

Comment: I suggested already: read the mans. It'll be the most straight way. Furthermore, the `cron` isn't so complicated utility.

Comment: Hey, just giving you an update here. After reading through the `cron` documentation I was able to get started. Thanks for your help.